# Python-xarray: How to combine multiples 3D DataArray into a single one with 6 dimensions?

Tags: python, raster, python-xarray

I already read 80 rasters geotif files of 12 bands (months), and I generated 80 3D DataArrays (so I can crop them by clip_box in order to plot 80 maps of my project area).

Now I need to combine them into a single DataArray, but along 3 more dimensions (climatic Model, Climate-Change scenario and time period). My objective is to compute statistics and to plot maps along the 4 differents dimensions.

On what function should I focus to do that ?
One of the 3 combining functions (concat, merge, combine_nested) ?

Comment: It is easy enough to try each of those three methods, maybe use portions of the DataArrays if they are large then evaluate the results.  You don't want to use a Dataset?.  Dd you look through the [How do I?](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/howdoi.html) list in the docs?

Comment: At the beginning of the [Combining data](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/combining.html) section of the user guide there are four *scenarios* and associated methods - which looks like it applies to you?

Comment: @ wwii, The doc is not so easy to understand. I have already read the Combining-data section http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/combining.html#combining-multi and make many tries without success. That's why I would like to know wich method is correct, so I can to focus on it with the help of the doc.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to merge multiples dataArrays along multiples dimension is to:

- first create an empty dataArray `da_to` with all the requested dimensions and coordinate lists (and set spatials dimensions)

```
dims= ('dim1', 'dim2', ...) 
array= np.empty((len(coord1_list), len(coord2_list), ...) 
da_tot= xr.DataArray(data= array, dims= dims, coords={'coord1': coord1_list, 'coord2': coord2_list, ..., 'lon': lon_list, 'lat': lat_list) 
da_tot.rio.set_spatial_dims(x_dim= 'lon', y_dim= 'lat', inplace= True)
```

- then add each dataArray `da` by assigning it with its coordinates

`da_tot.loc[dict(coord1= 'xxxx', coord2= 'yyyy', ....)]= da`